# how to install R 3.5.0 (old version ) on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

can anyone help me in installing older version of R 3.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried a lot to install it but i failed every time. Now asking this question here seems silly but i tried a lot to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu repositories seem to have only the 3.5.2 version, so this older version you would only find over CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/

There you have the r-base 3.5.0, AND you've got to resolve any dependency by hand, although the apt should give you what it needs. Some of the dependencies that my apt returns that I need here:

- r-base-core_3.5.0-1bionic_amd64.deb
- r-base-core-dbg_3.5.0-1bionic_amd64.deb
- r-base_3.5.0-1bionic_all.deb
- r-recommended_3.5.0-1bionic_all.deb

Maybe your apt asks you for other dependencies and brokens out the installation, just download them from the link above and redo the install.

BTW, for installing files already downloaded in your PC through terminal:

sudo apt install ./name-of-the-base-file.deb ***OR***
sudo apt install /path/for/the/file/here/name-of-the-base-file.deb

Comment: ./configure
 make

(If your make is not called `make', set the environment variable MAKE to
its name, and use that name throughout these instructions.) . " I DONT KOW HOW TO SET IT

Comment: From the R Installation and configuration guide:

"Unless you do not want to view graphs on-screen (or use a Mac) you need ‘X11’ installed, including its headers and client libraries. For recent Fedora distributions it means (at least) RPMs ‘libX11’, ‘libX11-devel’, ‘libXt’ and ‘libXt-devel’. On Debian we recommend the meta-package ‘xorg-dev’. If you really do not want these you will need to explicitly configure R without X11, using --with-x=no."

So, for Ubuntu, try:


sudo apt-get install xorg-dev


and after that proceed the compiling and installing of R.